# Both 3G modem and Wifi?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I need to be able to connect to a wifi network and send stuff over the 3g modem, is that possible?

I'm creating a little program that acts as a portforwarder between the client > internet > phone > wifi > "hardware connected to phone using Wifi"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported through the Android SDK, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

try this app http://www.redrails.com.br/2012/02/wireless-analyzer-for-android/ it activates both connections!